# Pass value with action sheet button

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, nsindexpath

I created an `ActionSheet` with action of button. I have button that opens the action sheet and the ActionSheet button opens new `viewController`. The problem is that the button which opens the action sheet is inside `tableview cell` and I do not know how to pass value with this button.

The concept should be something like this but with the action sheet button:

```
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit it", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
            //here I want to pass value to next viewController and open that VC.
           //Valu should be something like postsArray[indexPath.row]
  }))
```

Comment: *pass value* to what? Action Sheet or the viewController? Update your question with your actionSheet code Block and specify where exactly do you want that value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button action you are showing the `ActionSheet` and you want that button's index on `prepareforSegue` method, so you need to store the `IndexPath` of tapped button on the action of button and then present the `ActionSheet` for that declare one instance of type `IndexPath` and use it inside your button action.

```
var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath()

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let point = tableView.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: sender)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        //Add code for presenting ActionSheet
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editPost" {
        let dest = segue.destination as! EditPostViewController
        dest.selectedPost = postsArray[self.selectedIndexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the button inside cell managed like selectedIndexPath too like cell itself? But like this the selectedPost passed value is nil :(

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Don't understand what you try to say please explain more in detail.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using **delegate** method.

```
protocol ActionSheetDelegate{
   func transferSomeData(message : String)
  }

class customCell : UITableViewCell {

  var customCellDelegate : ActionSheetDelegate!

  ...
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit it", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
        self.customCellDelegate.transferSomeData(message : "yourMessage")
     })
    )
  ...


}
```

In your current **tableViewController**

```
class yourTableViewController : UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ActionSheetDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad(){


    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = customTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! customTableViewCell 

     cell.customCellDelegate = self

     return cell 

   }

 func transferSomeData(message : String){

       print(message)
       // Segue to someViewController

     }
  }
```