# How to call data within a custom class function from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a post class that I use to fill a collection view with post data from Firebase.
  I was having trouble getting some user data so I tried putting the observer in the post class.
  This seems to work fine, however there is a slight delay in getting the data from Firebase so it seems to finish the init() function before the firebase call is complete.  
This is the post class :

```
class Post {

    var _comment1Text: String?
    var _comment1User: String?
    var _comment1Name: String?

    init(comment1Text: String, comment1User: String, comment1Name: String) {

        self._comment1Text = comment1Text
        self._comment1User = comment1User
        self._comment1Name = comment1Name

        if self._comment1User != "" {
            DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(self._comment1User!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { userDictionary in
                let userDict = userDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
                self._comment1Name = userDict.objectForKey("username") as? String
            })
        }
        print(self._comment1Text)
        print(self._comment1Name)
    }
}
```

If I print within the firebase call, it works.
 However, if I print after it, for some reason, comment1name is not yet filled.
  Is there a way to get self._comment1Name to contain the data from Firebase in time to fill the collectionView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dravidian answer is on point. There may be another issue as well. Is your Post class a singleton? If it's not, you may want to re-consider your overall strategy. As the answer shows, Firebase is asynchronous and time has to be allowed for Firebase to retrieve data from the internet, and there's always lag when that happens. So you need to ensure you don't work with data before Firebase has time to retrieve it. The Firebase data is valid ONLY inside the block (closure) so don't work on that data until it returns. Doing that with a set of objects is going to be tricky.

Comment: Yeah when I read that it's asynchronous I knew what to do.  Had to change strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(self._comment1User!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value
```

is an **Asynchronous call**, So access your print functions inside the completionBlock and you have to update your collectionView inside the completionBlock.

```
 DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(self._comment1User!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { userDictionary in
            let userDict = userDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
            self._comment1Name = userDict.objectForKey("username") as? String

                print(self._comment1Text)
                print(self._comment1Name) 
                // Update your collectionView      
        })
```

**Asynchronous call**'s are loaded in a different network thread, so it takes some time to retrieve the DB from the server.

If you are looking for communicating between a custom class and you viewController look at my this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40160637/6297658